# Как получить значение из реестра без префикса #?

Tags: windowsinstaller, wix

Использую WiX 3.10.

В реестре в `HKLM\SOFTWARE\C001\F001` в `Value001` типа `DWORD` храняться целые значение, например `2`.
В WiX получаем это значение в проперть `P001`:

```
<Property Id="P001" Secure="yes" Value="1">
  <RegistrySearch
    Id="REGISTRY_KEY_001"
    Type="raw"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\C001\F001"
    Name="Value001" />
</Property>
```

В этом случае целое значение `2` из реестра записывается, как `#2`.
И в таком же виде это значение будет записваться дальше, например:

```
 <RegistryValue Name="Value002" Type="integer" Value="[P001]" Action="write" />
```

В результате в реестре будет создано поле типа `REG_SZ` со значенем `#2`.

Как правильно получить значение из реестра, чтобы не было префикса `#`?